# not able to use acceleration values kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, accelerometer

I need help with accessing acceleration values from my device , I am able to read values and update respective label.text In .kv file but I am not able to perform any calculation on accessed values, just updating label.text works but if try to write it down to a file (using file handling functions) or append the values to a list (usinf list.append)then error occurs , is their any alternative to the above mentioned methods..??

Edited:

```
lst = []
class AppLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppLayout,self).__init__()
        self.sensor_status = True
    def do_toggle(self):
        if self.sensor_status:
            try:
                accelerometer.enable()
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.get_acceleration,1.0/24)

                self.sensor_status = False
                self.ids.togglebutton.text = 'Stop'

            except():
                self.ids.value.text = 'Failed'
        else:
            self.sensor_status = True
            self.ids.togglebutton.text = 'Start'
            self.ids.value.text = 'start again'
            accelerometer.disable()
            Clock.unschedule(self.get_acceleration)
    def get_acceleration(self,dt):
        try:
            self.ids.value.text= str(accelerometer.acceleration[0])
            #lst.append.str(accelerometer.acceleration[0])
            #self.module.write.text = str(accelerometer.acceleration[0])
        except:
            self.ids.value.text = 'Failed to read'
class AccelerometerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AppLayout()
if __name__=="__main__":
    AccelerometerApp().run()
```

the above codes works for updating label.. if i add any other line into get_acceleration function(commented line) .. accelerometer fails to give values.. am i taking this the wrong way.. or should i still learn more abt kivy..?

Comment: File handling and calculations work. Show us your code so that we can help you.

Comment: try block in get_acceleration() only updates on value only.. updating two will result in not bale to update both

Comment: If you do `val = accelerometer.acceleration[0]` as the first statement in the `try` block, then replace the other uses of `accelerometer.acceleration[0]` with `val`, does that help?

Comment: yes it helped thank you..

Comment: once I use val I can send it over network using sockets to and write to file simultaneously ..thank u fr ur help